# Is there a simpler way or different way I can approach this flag validation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this validation that only seems to work sometimes and I don't know why unless there is something that I am not seeing. I want to use the flag variable for later on.

```
var flag = false

var productos_grupo_promocion = [ { "idgrupo": 1, "cantidad_producto": 5 }, { "idgrupo": 6, "cantidad_producto": 1 } ]
            
var arr = [ { "idgrupo": 1, "cantidad": 5 }, { "idgrupo": 6, "cantidad": 1 } ]

productos_grupo_promocion.forEach(function (obj){

   var matched_elements = arr.filter(item => item.idgrupo == obj.idgrupo)

   matched_elements.forEach(function(item){
      if(parseInt(obj.cantidad_producto) == parseInt(item.cantidad)){
         flag = true
      }else{
         flag = false
      }
   }) 
})
```

Comment: Should the `flag` only indicate that there was 1 match? In that case, use `Array.some` instead of `forEach` (in both cases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current problem you have is, in case your last product has matching elements, but does not match the last matched_element, it will set the `flag` to `false`.

Assuming you want to have `flag` set to `true` as soon as you have 1 match, you should use [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

If you want that everything matches, you should use [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) but `return false` in case there are no `matched_elements`.

So I am assuming you want to exit early, and just change your logic to

```js
var productos_grupo_promocion = [{
  "idgrupo": 1,
  "cantidad_producto": 5
}, {
  "idgrupo": 6,
  "cantidad_producto": 1
}]

var arr = [{
  "idgrupo": 1,
  "cantidad": 5
}, {
  "idgrupo": 6,
  "cantidad": 1
}]

function hasMatch(promos, tags) {
  return promos.some(function(obj) {
    var matched_elements = tags.filter(item => item.idgrupo == obj.idgrupo);

    return matched_elements.some(function(item) {
      return parseInt(obj.cantidad_producto) == parseInt(item.cantidad);
    });
  });
}

console.log(hasMatch(productos_grupo_promocion, arr));
```

As this would end, as soon as 1 match was found. Which is what I believe you want to achieve.

As I am not entirely sure if that would be enough for the future, why not change that you get all the promotion items that actually match, say in the following way?

```js
const productos_grupo_promocion = [{
  "idgrupo": 1,
  "cantidad_producto": 5
}, {
  "idgrupo": 6,
  "cantidad_producto": 1
}, {
  "idgrupo": 6,
  "cantidad_producto": 5
}];

const arr = [{
  "idgrupo": 1,
  "cantidad": 5
}, {
  "idgrupo": 6,
  "cantidad": 1
}];

function getMatchingPromotions(promotions, tags) {
  const promoDict = promotions.reduce((map, promo) => map.set(promo.idgrupo, (map.get(promo.idgrupo) ?? []).concat( promo )), new Map());
  return tags.reduce((resultArr, tag) => {
    const matches = promoDict.get(tag.idgrupo);
    if (!matches) {
      return resultArr;
    }
    return resultArr.concat(matches.filter(p => p.cantidad_producto === tag.cantidad));
  }, []);
}

console.log( getMatchingPromotions(productos_grupo_promocion, arr) );
```

This one would first group all the promotions, and then find all matches per tag.

I'm not sure what your use case afterwards might be so maybe the second version is overthinking it, in which case the first one would fix your logic.

Comment: The first solution solved my problem but with Array.every, thank you!